# Error in installing lollipop 5.0.2 on Samsung s2 (19105p) pluse

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, android-versions, android-device-manager

Im trying to install lollipop on my Samsung s2 pluse (19105p). But at installing time got a error in " E:failed to  verify whole-file signatures "
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to install CyanogenMod 12 custom ROM using the built-in "3e" recovery.  This will not work, as the stock recovery only allows updates that are signed by keys only known to your carrier, manufacturer (Samsung in this case) or Google themselves.

You will first need to find anf install a custom recovery image that is built specifically for your phone's model, which is GT-i9105P.  A quick Google search leads to [these](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2663834) instructions on XDA-Developers forum on installing a build of ClockworkMod  (a.k.a. CWM) recovery on your device.

You will need USB drivers for your phone model installed on your computer, [Odin utility](http://odindownload.com/), and the custom recovery image from [here](http://d-h.st/II4).

1. First, turn your phone off completely.  Remove the battery for good measure.
2. Boot the phone into Download mode by holding <kbd>Power</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> + <kbd>Volume down</kbd> buttons together.
3. Connect the phone to your PC and wait for drivers to install and recognize it.
4. Run the Odin utility, and ensure that one of the squares highlights, signifying that it recognized the phone.  If this doesn't happen it means the USB drivers are not correct, and you will need to find different ones, probably from Samsung's support site.
5. Select the "PDA" (or "AP" depending on version) button, and select the recovery image file you downloaded.
6. Un-check the "Auto-reboot" option and click the "Start" button.  This may take a while.
7. Once the flashing process completes, the highlighted square should say "RES OK" or "PASS!".  Disconnect the phone from USB, and take out the battery.

Now you should be able to boot into custom recovery, and that will allow you to flash a custom ROM like CyanogenMod.

Comment: ClockworkMode(cwm) recovery posible in android 4.1.2 jelly Bean ?

Comment: My phone is not updated still nw. My phone have android 4.1.2 jelly bean. So here possible to do cwm recovery ?

Comment: Android OS version is not important.  As long as the bootloader is not locked (like on new phones,) you should be able to flash CWM recovery via Odin.